# Bluetooth undetected Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

I know there are similar questions to this one, but all of them are solved by adding a missing firmware in `/lib/firmware/ar3k`. That is not my problem here, given that:

`sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth`

gives out (please notice the absence of errors):

```
[    3.316369] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.316370] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.316375] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.316377] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.316380] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.275289] Bluetooth: hci0: Device setup in 139936 usecs
[    5.169408] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.169413] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.169417] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   12.779673] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   12.779688] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   12.779695] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

and moreover:

`ls /lib/firmware/ar3k`

gives out:

```
1020200      AthrBT_0x01020001.dfu  AthrBT_0x31010100.dfu    ramps_0x01020201_40.dfu
1020201      AthrBT_0x01020200.dfu  AthrBT_0x41020000.dfu    ramps_0x11020000_40.dfu
1020201coex  AthrBT_0x01020201.dfu  ramps_0x01020001_26.dfu  ramps_0x11020100_40.dfu
30000        AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu  ramps_0x01020200_26.dfu  ramps_0x31010000_40.dfu
30101        AthrBT_0x11020100.dfu  ramps_0x01020200_40.dfu  ramps_0x31010100_40.dfu
30101coex    AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu  ramps_0x01020201_26.dfu  ramps_0x41020000_40.dfu
```

Edit:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

gives me:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7961]
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:e0bc]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
```

`lsusb` returns:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 048d:c966 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8176)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e0cd Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56ff IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What is your BT device? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Here you go. Maybe there's a driver missing ? Incompatibility with the new release (unlikely imo, my laptop is 6 months old) ?

Comment: And where is `lsusb`?

Comment: Here it is. Any idea, then ?

Comment: The device seems to be supported. Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: The ouput is similar to the one of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: Is it a fresh install of 22.04? What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: It's an upgrade via `do-release-upgrade`. The kernel is on version 5.15.0-37-generic.

Comment: It should work with this kernel. What does `rfkill list` show?

Comment: Nothing is blocked, according to the command. Neither soft blocked nor hard blocked

Comment: You can try another kernel and report a bug. `ar3k` is unrelated. You have a Mediatek device.